# Creating markers within a loop

Tags: javascript, openlayers

Using OpenLayers, I want to display multiple markers over an OSM map by creating them from an array within a `while` loop.

The code works when I hard-code a single coordinate, but not when reading the coordinates from the array.

What can be done to construct the markers?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qmxrtnfo/9/

You can test it via:

```js
ol.proj.fromLonLat([lonlatarray[i]]) 
//  ol.proj.fromLonLat([16.332253, 48.503684])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare your coordinates as 2D array of numeric values.:

```js
var lonlatarray = [
[16.332253, 48.503684],
[16.432503, 48.565917],
[16.402290, 48.473580]
];
```

You can then call each coordinates in the loop using

```js
ol.proj.fromLonLat(lonlatarray[i])
```